# Shape of result: np.random.randn(10,5) @ np.random.randn(5)

Tags: numpy, broadcast

What is the shape of the result equals to 10 for this numpy equation: np.random.randn(10,5) @ np.random.randn(5).
Thank you folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation page for [`numpy.matmul`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html):

> If the second argument is 1-D, it is promoted to a matrix by appending
> a 1 to its dimensions. After matrix multiplication the appended 1 is
> removed.

This means after appending an extra dimension on the second operand, the operation is performed between two 2D arrays `(10, 5)` and `(5, 1)`. The matrix multiplication follows the `(i, j) @ (j, k) = (i, k)` rule, so the output is shaped `(10, 1)`, and the extra appended dimension is then removed: `(10,)`.

Comment: broadcasting doesn't apply to the last 2 dimensions of these arrays.  It's (10,5) with (5,1) giving (10,1) squeezed to (10,)